# How to automate SSL certificate importation

Tags: java, ssl

My application connects to outlook to post events. I often face SSL Hand Shake exception. So I have to manually import an SSL certificate from graph.microsoft.com very frequently.
Is there a way it can be automated?

I'm importing an SSL certificate into the java trust store every 45 days approximately.

Comment: You should never have to do this at all, let alone frequently. Surely Microsoft's certificate is signed by a CA?

Comment: There is no reason to import any certificates, the DigiCert Global Root G2 root is already in Java's cacerts file

Comment: I'm not sure but SSL hand shake exception being thrown after a while and it resolves ony after I'm importing  certificate manually.